# Deleting hard-linked directory on macOS?

Tags: macos, sync, symbolic-link, google-drive, hardlink

I have a directory on my macOS that I hard-linked to my Google Drive folder, using

```
gln -d "path to directory" "path to Google Drive folder"
```

If I try to remove the directory from my Google Drive folder, using

```
rm -r "path to directory inside Google Drive folder"
```

the directory on my macOS is *also* deleted. Is there a "safe" way to remove the directory from my Google Drive folder (i.e., one that will keep the original directory in place)?

Comment: If you've got the GNU `ln` (`gln`) on your system, then you probably have the whole GNU coreutils package (did you install it via Homebrew or MacPorts or what?). It might be interesting to see if the GNU coreutils version of `unlink(1)` can successfully unlink one hardlink of the directory without unlinking the other.

Comment: Yeah, I installed it via Homebrew. Can you elaborate on the unlink idea?

Comment: Well, I tried unlink and got an error, that the intended directory is a directory. Heh. Any other ideas? Thanks!